# Distinct/unique count nested in aggregation

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to alter a table, create a distinct count column and group by week.
Any Ideas?  I'm not sure how to wrap in multiple aggregations?

[Here is the table and desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkIws.png)

Here are before and after tables

[image]

Comment: I don't have more data to input - is that what you're asking for?

Comment: If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the transcription effort? Please don't use images of data, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar. ps: You can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to create ascii tables.

Comment: that helps, thank you

Comment: no problem. For future questions: please don't use images of data >> very frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**COUNT(distinct ...)** in a simple grouping query should work I believe

```
select week, theater, count(distinct person) as uniq_person
from yourtable
group by week, theater
```